# How to minimise role assignment usage when granting least privilege on lots of Azure service bus queues and topics

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I'm working in an Azure environment and hoping to achieve a least privilege grantable setup for Azure Service Bus queues and topics.

My company is running apps with user Managed Identities. We have an Azure Service Bus instance with nearly 1000 queues and topics, all in a single namespace with a failover region.

Each azure subscription has a hard limit of 4000 role assignments, according to the documentation. With Azure Service Bus, role assignments can only be granted at the namespace or resource (queue/topic) level.

I'm looking for ways to be able to grant the user managed identities, least privilege access to individual queues and topics, while using the minimum amount of role assignments.

The best way i can currently think to do this is to make a new custom role, which allows read/write on a resource and then create a new group for each queue/topic and assign the role assignment from the queue/topic resource to the corresponding group.

This would result in me using ~1000/subscription role assignments from the 4000/subscription limit. Or ~2000 if the send/receive roles were split out to achieve proper least privilege.

Are there any other ways of achieving this which use fewer role assignments?

Comment: Please edit your question and include some examples. It is not clear from the question that how many user assigned managed identities are there and what kind of permissions you would want to give to these identities. Also, is there an overlap of these permissions i.e. x number of identities will have y permissions.

Comment: @Guarav Mantri I think this is a perfectly reasonable question. It's asking for ways of reducing the number of role assignments at a high level, the specific numbers and details don't matter. It's an architectural/design question and is a well-known issue with Azure RBAC.